# Clear and efficient XPath that matches no element

Tags: xml, xpath

I have a library function that accepts some XPath arguments, and for one of them I want to supply one that would match no element.

I am currently using `*[false()]` but I don't think this is very efficient (a naive implementation will probably go through all elements).

Is there one that is at least as clear in intention (i.e. matches nothing) but more efficient?

(Type of the expression must be node list.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like @MaxToro's answer for brevity (+1), but here's a self-documenting alternative:

```
/impossible-to-match[false()]
```

Or, shorter:

```
/*[false()]
```

(By specifying a leading `/` to your current example, it will be very efficient.)

Answer (score 2):

Document parent `/..` is always empty.

Comment: It's a bit cryptic, but thanks for perhaps the shortest answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
./self::*[not(self::*)]  

./self::*[not(.)]
```

Basically this asks the for an xpath that matches the current node "./self::*" , and at the same time doesn't match the current node "[not(self::*)]" or "[not(.)]", which means it will match nothing.

Comment: Could you provide a bit of context to the answer and perhaps some explanation?